# tableau dateparse returns wrong date time format

Tags: datetime, tableau-api

I am using the `dateparse` function of Tableau, it mostly works OK, but certain strings are not calculated correctly. What I am doing wrong?

Data as follows times_cl2ended - `2016-08-19 12:52:32.534000`

I calculated a new modified field with the following formula

```
DATEPARSE("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSSSSS",[times_cl2ended])
```

But I get the result `2016-08-19 00:52:33`

I tried to play with locale setting from automatic to Sweden (I live in Sweden), but nothing changed. Can any Tableau guru help?

Comment: I don't know anything about Tableau, but I've stumbled upon this question and thought to comment. The error must be related to a wrong interpretation of the 12H/24H format, that is, it is either read incorrectly or printed incorrectly. Try parsing other strings: one around 08:00 (AM), one around 23:00 (that is, 11:00PM) and see how they are interpreted. It might be that changing the format (to e.g. `HH` instead of `hh`), or passing an additional parameter, solves the issue. And the seconds are being rounded up, for some reason that I can't imagine. Sorry if all of this was obvious.

Comment: Thanks Fabio.. I understood that is because of 12H/24H format issue, but did not know exactly how to solve this. But HH instead of hh actually solves this. Great help indeed.

Comment: Glad I could help. If you find a solution to the other problem (the seconds being rounded up), please post an answer here (unless there's already one by that time).